# Relevance of AWT in Java for Game Development

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm currently trying to familiarize myself with Java &, as part of that process, I have been browsing some online tutorials. My question is, I've heard that the AWT has been deprecated for some years now yet some of the tutorials I have seen posted as recently as last year on, say, programming a game has lines importing AWT, like:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

Should/can these lines be replaced by code using Swing type code instead, or do Java (game) developers still use AWT? I'm kind of confused what is or isn't used by Java programmers right now.

Comment: Swing is built on top of the AWT. Swing components inherit from AWT components. For GUIs, use only Swing components, but don't be afraid to use AWT events, layouts, printing ability, graphics, Java2D etc.

Comment: You can still use those in Swing.  Check out the [Java Tutorials](docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) to find many examples of how to use Swing components.

Comment: _I've heard that the AWT has been deprecated for some years now_ You just need to look at the _javadoc_ of a commonly used _Swing_ class, like [JPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPanel.html), for example, to see that it extends an AWT class. By the way, was one of the tutorials you looked at [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) ?

Comment: @Abra Sorry for the late reply, Abra.  No, it was an old YT vid.